# Properly escaping check_command in nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, haproxy

When I execute

```
sudo -u nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_by_ssh.sh hostname "check_haproxy -u \"http://localhost:10000/haproxy?stats\;csv\""
```

it runs perfectly on the server.

For this, I have this in my HAProxy.cfg

```
define service {
        use     generic-service
        hostgroup_name  pwmail-ee-oxweb
        service_description     HAProxy-ee
        servicegroups   ssh-dep
        check_command   check_by_ssh!check_haproxy -u \"http://localhost:10000/haproxy?stats\;csv\"
        contacts        sysad,mail-hosting-rt
}
```

It doesn't work. Says that `Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `check_by_ssh.sh` look like? Could you please show us the result of `check_haproxy -u \"http://localhost:10000/haproxy?stats\;csv\"`?

Comment: There's a standard check_by_ssh plugin.  What is check_by_ssh.sh?  A shell script that wraps the standard command, or something else?  Nagios wiki refers to http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/remotely-monitor-servers-with-the-nagios-checkbyssh-plugin/321 as an example for using the standard command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check_command   check_by_ssh!check_haproxy -u
>   'http://localhost:10000/haproxy?stats\;csv'

worked.